# Variation on coin-change

Tags: dynamic-programming, coin-change

So the typical coin-change problem asks you to figure out whether or not you can make change for a value v using unlimited coins of denomination x1, x2, ... , xn, but I was wondering how you might go about figuring out the same problem using each coin AT MOST once?

For the original problem I know you can iterate over prefixes of the value and see whether or not you can make change for v-x_i, but I'm at a loss when it's limited to at most one coin per denomination.

Any tips to just get me started? I was maybe thinking you could also iterate over prefixes of the denominations. Not sure though...

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved using dynamic programming.

I personally find it useful to draw a table to help derive an algorithm. Below is tan example table for coins of denominations 5,10,2,1 and total value V.

[image: help table]

First of all, we initialise the table with True for all i if v = 0 (for zero value, the change is always correct)

`For i: 0-> n D(v,0) = true`

Then we traverse the table, row by row (left to right) and column by column (up to down)

`For v: 1-> V
    For i: 0-> n`

It can be observed that we are able to give the change for the value v and coin xi in two scenarios:

- We were able to give change for value v - xi and for the previous coin x(i-1)

`D(v,i) = true if D(v-xi, i-1) = true`

Examples of that case include coin xi=5 (second column) and v=5 or coin xi=1 (last column) and v=6

- We were able to give change for the previous coin and same value. (If the value is 5 and we already had a coin 5, it doesn't matter how many coins we have afterwards - we already gave a full change.)

`D(v,i) = true if D(v, i-1) = true`

Example of such case is row 5.

In non of the above cases apply, we cannot give full change and `D(v,i)` is false. The final solution is the table element corresponding to total value V and index n.

To sum up:

```
  For i: 0-> n D(v,0) = true

  For v: 1-> V
    For i: 0-> n

    D(v,i)= D(v, i-1) V D(v-xi, i-1 )
    else D(v,i) = false;

  return D(V, n)
```

Link to fully coded solution in repl: https://repl.it/@majakudlicka/CoinChangeVariation

Answer (score 0):

for coin-change problem, u can use forward or backward recurrence. in ur statement, u used backward. here i'll give a forward method, and it can easily solve UNLIMITED version and AT-MOST-ONCE version

suppose f is a 1D boolean array. f[i] means whether u can make change for value i. initially, f[0]=true, others equals false.

UNLIMITED version:

```
for (int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    for (int j=0;j<v;j++)
        if (f[j])
            f[j+x[i]]=true;
```

AT-MOST-ONCE version:

```
for (int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    for (int j=v-1;j>=0;j--)
        if (f[j])
            f[j+x[i]]=true;
```

the only difference is the order for loop j.

an example which helps u understand:

suppose there is only one kind of coin which cost 2. ie x[1]=2. and v=10

after the 1st algorithm, u can get f[0]=f[2]=f[4]=f[6]=f[8]=f[10]=true.

but for the 2nd algorithm, u can only get f[0]=f[2]=true.

Comment: What if there is a 3D boolean array ? How to setup the at most once version without the time growing exponentially ?